# How to delete object from Parse via PFQuery

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I am trying to delete an object from the class UserRequests via swift only if the object belongs to the current user, and that requestResponded is not equal to true. However, I get an error at `objects.deleteInBackground()` and the function still doesn't work when I remove this line.

```
func deleteRequest(){
    let check = PFQuery(className: "UserRequests")
    check.whereKey("requestResponded", equalTo: "True")

    let query = PFQuery(className: "UserRequests")
    query.whereKey("username", equalTo: (PFUser.currentUser()?.objectForKey("username") as! String))
    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({ (objects, error) -> Void in
        if objects != nil && error == nil{
            // Successfully retrieved the object
            check.getFirstObjectInBackgroundWithBlock {
                (object: PFObject?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
                if error != nil || object == nil {
                    print("Not accepted.")
                    object!.deleteInBackground()
                    objects.deleteInBackground()
                } else {
                    print("Successfully retrieved the object.")
                }
            }
        }else{
            self.performSegueWithIdentifier("requestAccepted", sender: self)
        }
    })
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because objects is an list of object. You should only delete object 1 by 1.

For example:

```
for object in objects {
    object.deleteInBackground()
}
```

Also, because two queries belong to same class. I would suggest using 1 query

**UPDATE**

```
func deleteRequest(){
    let query = PFQuery(className: "UserRequests")
    // the key "requestResponded" is not True
    query.whereKey("requestResponded", equalTo: "False")
    // for deleting the object is that it belongs to the current user
    query.whereKey("username", equalTo (PFUser.currentUser()?.objectForKey("username") as! String))
    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({ (objects, error) -> Void in
        if error != nil{
            print(error)
        }
        //  objects are those the key "requestResponded" is not True and belongs to the current user
        for object in objects {
            object.deleteInBackground()
        }
        // other case
        if objects.count == 0 { // no match result found
        }
    })
}
```

I guess you still miss the condition of when to perform segue

Comment: Thank you. How can I use 1 query for this?

Comment: First, you need to think about conditions like what is the condition for deleting objects? what is the condition for performing segue? How about else case?

Comment: Alright. As mentioned in the question, the condition for deleting the object is that it belongs to the current user, AND that the key "requestResponded" is not True.

Comment: Perfect, it works! Thank you so much! I just realized there's no need for a segue within this particular function. Again, thank you.